# Java build: Executing manifest /build/null2120978844 is invalid

Tags: java, manifest

I've built this project several times in the past. Suddenly it started doing this:

```
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/built-clean.properties
Deleting directory /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build
Updating property file: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/built-jar.properties
Created dir: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/classes
Created dir: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/empty
Compiling 14 source files to /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 51 files to /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/classes
compile:
Created dir: /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/dist
Copying 1 file to /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build
/home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/nbproject/build-impl.xml:676: Existing manifest /home/adam/code/HeimdallOneClick/build/null2120978844 is invalid
BUILD FAILED (total time: 4 seconds)
```

I don't know how to fix this.  The manifest is quite long, but here's the section it's failing on.

```
<target depends="init,-do-jar-with-libraries-create-manifest,-do-jar-with-libraries-copy-manifest" if="do.archive+main.class.available" name="-do-jar-with-libraries-set-main">
    <manifest file="${tmp.manifest.file}" mode="update">
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
    </manifest>
</target>
```

What do I do for troubleshooting?  Is there some way to rebuild the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer

i went and looked at the /null file.. It was my manifest.mf file...

```
adam@Adam-Desktop:~/code/HeimdallOneClick/build$ cat ./null1074768958 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
<requestedExecutionLevel
level="requireAdministrator"
uiAccess="true|false"/>
```

I had put that line in several days ago, before I realized how much was required to gain administrator access in Windows,  and I guess it did not pick it up until I committed to the SVN server...   Suddenly it started failing out.

Deleted the requestedexecutionlevel information and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `SplashScreen` in the first line in manifest like:

```
SplashScreen-Image: "Here the path of your Image"
Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```